# Angular Route Not exist when i paste the url in the browser

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-routing

I'm using angular4 and after i upload the project on the server when i enter this link:

[Dashboard](https://unisah.net/heroes/dashboard)

it gives me 404 not found but the dashboard in defined as router

but when i enter here :

[Heroes](https://unisah.net/heroes)

it redirects me to the dashboard which working fine

Comment: Please give a [mcve] **in the question**.

Comment: you can enter the two links and you will see:

1. https://unisah.net/heroes/dashboard

2. https://unisah.net/heroes

Comment: Yes, and you put those in the question, but you **haven't shown any code**. It is a fundamental requirement of a question to have a MCVE that shows *the code that doesn't work*, because otherwise how on earth can anyone tell you what you've done wrong?!

Comment: this is the point i don't know the place of the wrong in code because navigation and Routers Working fine but the link isn't working please give me minute i'll upload the full code on github

Comment: We don't want *"the full code of the project"* - evidently you don't want to trawl through the project figuring out what's wrong, and it's *your project*, so why do you think anyone else wants to? Isolating the source of the problem is part of *your job* in asking a question (or avoiding doing so, as you may figure it out in the process). Read [ask], and either give a [mcve] or delete the question. Off site links (except as *supplements*) and code dumps are **not** acceptable.

Comment: i may said something wrong i'm learning angular not expert in it this is the original project :
https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview
i just don't know what's the problem in code i'm fully new on angular 

so i'm so sorry if you think anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Working Solution for me is :

to add .htaccess file in project directory with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

and it's working fine anyone can enter this url :

[Dashboard](https://unisah.net/heroes/dashboard)